# Oracle PDO for PHP5.4 on CentOS7

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, driver

I am trying to set up a driver for Oracle on a PHP script on CentOS7 with Apache.

I have followed the steps at:

[image: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=31815]

And OCI does show up in phpinfo(), but whenever I try to use the driver, it throws a PDOException that it can't find the driver.

[image]

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Is `oci8` even a PDO driver? You may have to use `oci_*` functions...

Comment: You installed OCI driver but try to use PDO. Hmmmm...

Comment: Since OCI8 is recommended over PDO_OCI, you are in luck.  (OCI8 has better features, and is able to take advantage of automatic Oracle features like caching and DRCP).

Comment: Would you be so kind to show us the code that throws the exception please? and if possible the error itself.

Comment: If I do something like ` print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers()); ` then it will show mysql and sqlite. If I try a query like ` $dbh = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$tns,$db_username,$db_password); ` then that will error out and say driver not found.

Comment: I am working on some older software that requires me to use PDO, but I have been searching everywhere for a PDO installation that works and can't find one yet.

Comment: Don't mean to answer my own question, but after you guys said that oci8 isn't a PDO driver I found this chinese article that showed me how to install the PDO Driver. http://eggchang.pixnet.net/blog/post/42916280-centos-7-%2B-php-5.6-%E9%80%A3%E7%B7%9A-oracle-%28pdo_oci%29